# Annihilator of a simple module 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Annihilator of a simple module](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182742/annihilator-of-a-simple-module)

Let me ask the same question as [before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182742/annihilator-of-a-simple-module) because I still have trouble understanding the problem.

Let $R$ be a finitely generated commutative ring and $C$ an $R$-algebra ($C$ is not necessarily commutative). Assume that $C$ is a finitely generated $R$-module.

If $S$ is a simple $C$-module, then it seems known that the annihilator $I=Ann_{C}(S)$ of $S$ is of the form $I=\mathfrak{m}C$ for some maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ of $R$. Could anyone provide me of a proof?

Comment: It would be better to edit your old question or comment on Matt E's answer to say why you don't understand it.  This is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

To make explicit a counterexample that Matt E hinted at in the previous question you linked to: let $R$ be a field (I don't know what you mean by "finitely generated commutative ring"), $C=R\times R$ (direct product of rings) which is a finitely generated $R$-algebra, and $S=R$, viewed as $C$-module by the first factor of $R\times R$ (the second component is ignored). This is certainly a simple module, and $I=\mathrm{Ann}_{C}(S)=\{0\}\times R$ is not of the form $I=\mathfrak{m}C$ for any maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ of $R$ (indeed $\mathfrak m=\{0\}$ would be the only choice, and it fails).

Comment: Thank you for the detail counterexample, Marc. Now that I have a better understanding. I appreciate your assistance.